# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'client_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-6

I'm trying to relate the post with the client by sending "client_id" through request post then when I create it, it gives this exception:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'client_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`content`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sadadad, 2020-09-17 18:26:38, 2020-09-17 18:26:38))

```html
<form role="form" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('POST') }}

    @include('includes.errors')
    <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="{{ $client->id }}">

    <textarea type="text" class="form-control form-control-md" placeholder="what's in your mind ?" name="content"></textarea>

    <div style="margin: 10px 0;">
        <input type="file" hidden id='upload-photo' name="image">
        <label for="upload-photo" class="post-adds" ><i class="far fa-file-image fa-lg"></i></label>
        <input type="file" hidden id='upload-video' name="video">
        <label for="upload-video" class="post-adds" ><i class="far fa-file-video fa-lg"></i></label>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary " type="submit" style="display: inline; float:right;">Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`migrations:`

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('content')->nullable();
            $table->integer('likes')->default(0);
            $table->integer('shares')->default(0);
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('video')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

`controller:`

```
$request->validate([
            'video'=> 'mimes:mp4| max:20000',
            'image'=>'image | max:2000',
            'content'=>'required',
        ]);

        $request_data = $request->except('video','image');

        if($request->image){
            $img = Image::make($request->image);

            $img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });

            $img->save(public_path('dist/img/posts/'.$request->image->hashName()),60);

            $request_data['image'] = $request->image->hashName();
        }

        if($request->video){
            $vid = $request->video;

            $vid_name = rand().'.'.$vid->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $vid->move(public_path('dist/vid/posts'),$vid_name);

            $request_data['video'] = $vid_name;
        }

        Post::create($request_data);

        session()->flash('success',__('site.post_created_successfully'));
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
```

Comment: try setting the default value of this column to null inside DB and then try should work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `client_id` in `fillable` array in your `Post` model like so

```
protected $fillable = [
    ...

    'client_id',

    ...
];
```

**Another Solution**

You can add in your `Post` model

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

this will make all attributes mass assignable

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that can be considered, I have experienced it.

1. The `client_id` field is not a `nullable` column so it must have an auto-increment function
2. Because the `client_id` field is not a `nullable` column please specify its contents when entering a new row

According to the official laravel documentation [(here)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations), the `->unsigned()` function on a migration just adds the UNSIGNED attribute to the column without adding the AUTO INCREMENT attribute.

If this is the case, you have 2 options.

1. Added the `->autoIncrement()` function to the `client_id` column for migration
2. Change the column type to `->foreignId('user_id')` (which means delete the existing `->unsigned()` function)